# Calculating % Grade from latitude and longitude

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate % Grade from GPS points.  I am using the basic equation of

$$\dfrac{\text{Rise}}{\text{Run}} \times 100$$

The problem is I am getting spikes in my GPS data (example $1$ meter rise for $3$ meter run), I am guessing because of the fluctuation of the Vertical Accuracy of the GPS.

Has anyone dealt with this scenario or know of a way of weeding out the anomalies?

Comment: Welcome to GPS altitude. It sucks.

Comment: GPS altitude estimations are just bad. Part of this is because of the issues with geoid models. Part of this has got to be because of noise. And I'm not really sure what else could cause it, but I've looked at *lots* of GPS data, and I've never been able to use altitude data by itself.

Comment: suggest to move this question to SE GIS: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/how-to-get-an-elevation-profile-for-a-gps-track

Comment: You could take $n$ samples, use the median height of the first and last $m<\frac n2$ samples, use their difference as your rise and the length of the path between the associated sample points as your run. The median should get rid of single outliers, whereas the agp between the samples should eliminate systematic problems. Of course all of this will reduce resolution, but depending on your application it might be sufficient.

Comment: @Arkamis If you've "never been able to use altitude data by itself" have you resolved an issue similar to mine using altitude data in addition to other values?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi thank you for the suggestion.  Not sure if there is was a better way to ask ask the question in both locations, but I posted the question in the SE GIS SE as well.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for the suggestion.  I will give it a try this morning, but unfortunately the calculation is used to provide real time data so I am not sure I will be able to get a large enough 'gap' while still maintaining quasi real time data to the user.

Comment: Providing [a pointer to the corresponding question on GIS SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/67100/20475) would be helpful, and perhaps similarly for the other direction.

Comment: Per user suggestion question also posted on gis.stackexchange: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67100/calculating-accurate-grade-from-gps-coordinates

Comment: @KBurnell yes, I used 6dof accelerometer data + inertial nav techniques. Those induced other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you'll one reading per second. so you can make an average of 5 readings taken over that second and also average it with reading of previous second(s)

say reading in previous second is $$P$$
and 5 readings in this second is $$r1, r2, r3, r4, r5$$

you could do $$ r = (r1+r2+r3+r4+r5)/5$$
then final reading $$R = (P+r) /2$$

I have done this while measuring temperature with nasty sensors. should work with gps too :)

Comment: The usefulness of this technique depends entirely on the nature of the error sources for your application. There is no a priori reason to expect it to work for GPS data as well as it does for your temperature sensors. What I have seen (both in analysis of error and in my own GPS tracks) suggests that the error has trends over periods longer than one second, so all this technique will do is average a bunch of measurements that are all too high (or all too low).